# how to optimize query with conditional join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I need to optimize a query in which a join depends on a condition

I have two tables

Table1 has two columns, lets call them A and B columns, that can relate to table2 column C,

if column B is null, i have to match t1.A with t2.C
if column B is not null, i have to match t1.B with t2.C

and finally i need to know which entries on t1 have no match on t2...

To give more detail, t1 is a table of clients, and both A and B are client codes.
A codes are never the same as B codes, and in cases where there is B, B has precedence (B is the new client code, but old clients don't have it. In the case that B is null, A is the code to use) (all this because B column is new and old clients have null values for B).

t2 is a table of purchases. t2.C is the client code, but in this case is a single column, it stores A codes for old clients, and B codes for new clients.

The only thing i want is to know which clients have no purchases yet, with a query as efficient as possible.

I've come up with several queries, but they are extremely slow, I guess because of how the condition is handled:

First attempt:

```
select * 
from t1
left join t2 on (t1.A = t2.C or t1.B = t2.C)
where t2.D is null;
```

Note that i can use an OR condition, because i KNOW that t1.A will never be the same as any t1.B, so in t2.C, it coult only match with either A or B but never both (assume that condition is guaranteed). The query is so slow it timed out in my sql client.

Second attempt

```
select * 
from t1
left join t2 on (if(t1.B is null, t1.A = t2.C, t1.B = t2.C))
where t2.D is null;
```

In this case, the comparision condition depends on t1.B, if is null, it compares with A, and if it's not, with B.
Again, query is extremely slow.

I guess i could just use TWO joins, and use each condition (A or B) for each join, but i don't know exactly how to achieve it, specially because i need to get only the cases in which neither A o B have a match on t2. (that is, t1 clients without t2 purchases)

What are my options to build more efficient queries for such a case?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no indexes on `t1.A` or `t1.B` then I suspect [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) will be your best bet:

```
select * 
from t1
left join t2 on ifnull(t1.B, t1.A) = t2.C
where t2.D is null;
```

However, if either column is indexed, I suspect you will get the best performance by using `UNION ALL`:

```
select * 
from t1
left join t2 on t1.A = t2.C
where t2.D is null
and t1.B is null
union all
select * 
from t1
left join t2 on t1.B = t2.C
where t2.D is null
and t1.B is not null;
```

The reason being that during compilation the optimiser will not know whether to use `t1.A` or `t1.B` for the join so can't pick an index and will opt for a table scan, but if you separate it into two queries it knows which column to use on the join, and can use the appropriate index.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec7d30/2)**

Comment: thanks! the first version, (with `ifnull`) works pretty well, what i see is very similar to my second attempt in which i use `on (if(t1.B is null, t1.A = t2.C, t1.B = t2.C))` instead of your `on ifnull(t1.B, t1.A) = t2.C`. What makes them so different that your version is WAY more efficient than mine? I find that really interesting. And in fact, your ifnull version works faster than the union all, (.2 vs .6 seconds) despite i have indexes for all the involved columns (A,B and C).

Comment: The reason `IFNULL` is working better than your if statement is because the column `t2.C` is not contained within it, it is static so MySQL knows that it can use the index on this column, whereas in your if statement it can't worked out that `t2.C` is used in both the true and false expressions so it doesn't use the index.

Comment: oh now i get it! so it is not because of simply using `ifnull(x,y)` instead of `if(x is null,y,x)`, but because the comparing column being outside of the `if`. So using `(if(t1.B is null, t1.A, t1.B) = t2.C)` is the exact same thing as with ifnull(). Thanks!

Comment: accepted this answer, but answer by Gordon Linoff is also correct, and in fact it runs faster if having indexes.

Comment: The UNION ALL tip nailed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

Alas, doing conditional joins tends to result in very poor query performance.  In this case, you are testing for two values and presumably looking to see if neither one exists.  Try breaking this into two joins:

```
select * 
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.A = t2.C left join
     t2 t2a
     on t1.B = t2a.C
where t2.D is null and t2a.D is null;
```

This will allow the query to use indexes on A, B, and C.